# Maven Android SDK Deployer run the command "mvn install" error: Properties file not found. The file path seems not correct

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-2:read-project-properties (default) on project android-17: Properties file not found: D:\maven-android-sdk-deployer-master\platforms\android-17\${env.ANDROID_HOME}\platforms\android-17\source.properties -> [Help 1]
>
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-2:read-project-properties (default) on project android-17: Properties file not found: D:\maven-android-sdk-deployer-master\platforms\android-17\${env.ANDROID_HOME}\platforms\android-17\source.properties

1. I'm using maven on windows.
2. ANDROID_HOME has been set. The value is D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk
3. I could find source.properties under D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\platforms\android-17
4. D:\maven-android-sdk-deployer-master\platforms\android-17\${env.ANDROID_HOME}\platforms\android-17\source.properties should be D:\maven-android-sdk-deployer-master\platforms\android-17\D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\platforms\android-17\platforms\android-17\source.properties. It's not a valid path. I think that's what cause the failure.

Please tell me how to fix the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same issue. It can be resolved by opening the Android SDK Manager, removing the item which is producing the error (in your case the Android 4.2.2 API 17 SDK) and then once its removed simply install it again before you run the deployer again.