# Android Maven Deployer

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin

I am using the [mosabua android deployer](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer) to deploy android libraries to my local maven repo.

I am experiencing the following error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-2:read-project-properties
>   (default) on project android-19: Properties file not found:
>   /Users/sam/Documents/Development/maven-android-sdk-deployer/platforms/android-19/Users/sam/Documents/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platforms/android-19/source.properties

It seems the deployer is concatinating 2 directories so the source.properties file is not found. The 2 directories are ..

/Users/sam/Documents/Development/maven-android-sdk-deployer/platforms/android-19/

and

Users/sam/Documents/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platforms/android-19/

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Just to try and get it working I modified the this line in the POM 
../../../adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/

And everything is working fine. What is the original problem?

Comment: Deployer worked correctly for me as provided. Not sure what went wrong with yours, have you compared your main POM with the one on https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer/blob/master/pom.xml or https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer/blob/master/platforms/android-19/pom.xml and see if there are any differences?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven Android SDK Deployer run the command "mvn install" error: Properties file not found. The file path seems not correct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994808/maven-android-sdk-deployer-run-the-command-mvn-install-error-properties-file)